# I have a problem with jsonplaceholder using fetch. It is showing me unidentified. please let me the issue as soon as possible pls

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch

//javasciprt code to display the comment api

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      const title = json.title;
      const body = json.body;
      document.getElementById("printTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("printBody").innerHTML = body;
    });
```

//html code supporting this js file

```
 <div >
            TITLE
            <span id="printTitle">
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="news-content-1">
            BODY
            <span id="printBody">
            </span>
          </div>
```

Comment: That API is returning an array of objects not a single one

Comment: please can you tell me how can we display array of elements? @Remesh

Answer (score 0):

@Faizan Lambe,

Please see the below javascript snippet for your query.

```
let list = document.querySelector('#list');
function loadData(){
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      var obj = json[I];
      addList(obj);
    }
});
}
// Add Lists
function addList(obj){
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let p = document.createElement('p')
    let t = document.createTextNode(obj.title);
    p.appendChild(t);
    li.appendChild(p);
    list.appendChild(li);
}
```

-----html----

in html, I kept list tag  as below,

```
<ul id="list">
                    
</ul>
```

Using the addlist function, adding the title to this list.

Please check at your side.

Comment: didn't get the output @jrhamza

Comment: @FaizanLambe, Please see the jsfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/m5gp2shj/

Comment: @FaizanLambe, I hope this solves the problem, and please mark as answered if solves. ;)